# Is it prohibited to derive benefit from a mixture of milk and meat if the animal was improperly slaughtered?

Tags: halacha, animals, rambam, meat-and-milk

Is it prohibited to derive benefit from a mixture of milk and meat if the animal was improperly slaughtered? Assume the animal slaughtered, like the milk-giving animal, is kosher, but the slaughter did not meet standards of kashrus. Would one be permitted to derive benefit from the mixture (i.e. feeding it to a pet)?

It seems that Rambam writes about this in his commentary to the Mishna (Keritut 3:4), but that his opinion is not widely considered normative. Why not?

Comment: It seems that Rambam writes about this in his commentary to the Mishna (Keritut 3:4), but that his opinion is not widely considered normative.

Comment: SAH you are indeed correct...but I wonder why you ask when it seems you know the answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, ... or if the question is really "Why isn't the Rambam's opinion on this normative?", go ahead and cite the Rambam and ask that question.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it is permitted, however I have to look it up.

Comment: @SethJ I recall concluding that it is a forbidden mixture (assuming cow/sheep/goat).  I'll have to find a source as well, but why would you think that it is not a forbidden mixture?

Comment: @Isaac Moses, fixed. YDK, maybe he thinks it's not forbidden for the same reasons as the Rambam

Comment: OK, so we're off halacha and on the Rambam.

Comment: @YDK, I just looked it up. It looks like my point [was addressed by Shalom](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15577/5). I'll post a follow-up to provide an explanation for the position.

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam calls his opinion on this matter "a wondrous point." (*Nekuda nifla'a*); other Rishonim disagree with him and say that any bovine meat cooked in bovine milk is prohibited from benefit.

The Achronim (later authorities) followed the non-Rambam opinion, with notable exception of the Dagul Mervava (known to most as Rabbi Yechezkel Landau, aka the Noda Bihuda). His opinion is occasionally employed when combined with other reasons for leniency, but generally is considered a minority one.

Comment: [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10023/1172)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is the opinion that he is calling a wondrous point.  He seems to take the halacha for granted.  His big chidush is being able to circumvent issur mosif.

Answer (score 5):

The Sha'arei Simcha (Sha'ar2:4; brought in Darkei Teshuva) and Arugas Habosem say it's Mutar Behano. The Dogul Meirvava relies on tha Rambam Bemokom Hefseid that it's Mutar Behano. (See Chasam Sofer Siman 92 about this Dogul Meirvava.) Yad Avrohom says it's Mutar.